# DBeaver 22.2.0 - Can't parse numeric value [TRUE] using formatter

Tags: mysql, sql, dbeaver

### Im new to using DBeaver and have not found an answer to this question elsewhere.

I downloaded a CSV of [police shootings](https://www.kaggle.com/datasets/ramjasmaurya/us-police-shootings-from-20152022)  from Kaggle.com and have been trying to import it into DBeaver but i keep getting this error.
[image: Can't parse numeric value [TRUE] using formatter]

Initially I thought that it was having trouble with the BOOL data types because it changes them into 'tinyint(1)' automatically.

If I click "Skip" then I end up with a table of headers and no actual data.

```
SELECT *
FROM police_shootings_2015_2022;
```

[image]

DBeaver lets me inspect the csv before uploading it and this is what it looks like, [image]

Comment: Also, I understand that Bool and Boolean are synonyms for TINYINT(1). A value of zero is considered false. Non-zero values are considered true. So does DBeaver not accept TRUE and False Values but instead only 0 and 1??

Comment: So does DBeaver not accept TRUE and False Values - not quite import runs load data infile which sees true and false as strings. You might want to run load data infile instead of import wizard using input pre-processing - see https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/80727/converting-falsestring-to-falseboolean-during-load-data-local-infile

Answer (score 0):

I've encountered that same error message in DBeaver v22.2.2 (current version as I'm answering this) claiming numeric value for a string but the thing is that was not the issue itself. My problem was there where some apostrophes (') in the values trying to fill one column ("name") of my table. I think that could be a problem in an import like this one you want to do, e.g. you encounter a surname like "O'Leary". Replacing that surname for "OLeary" (removing the apostrophe in all values that had one) solved the problem for me. So, as that error message appeared for me misindicating the issue, I recommend that you first recheck the values you want to insert. Hope this helps!

Comment: It was the same for me with the double ones  ("). I guess it depends on your formatting.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to import in existing table and in new variant you changed something so it can be data type conflict. The easiest way is making import in new table and then delete old one and rename a new one.